# Unique Topological Sort for DAG

Tags: graph-theory, sorting, topological-graph-theory

I have a DAG (directed acyclic graph) which has more than one valid topological sorting. I'm looking for a way to sort it topologically and always get the same, well defined result.

For example take this graph:

```
A-->B
A-->C
B-->D
C-->D
```

There are two solutions to a topological sort:

```
1: A, B, C, D and
2: A, C, B, D
```

We notice that `B` and `C` can be sorted in any order. Therefore we choose alphabetic sorting as secondary sorting to get only one solution: `A, B, C, D`.

Here's an other example:

```
E-->G
E-->H
H-->F
```

There are three solutions to a topological sort:

```
1: E, G, H, F
1: E, H, G, F
3: E, H, F, G
```

But here, there's no obvious solution. No solution seems to be more "alphabetic" than the others.

Is there a way to get a unique, deterministic solution for any DAG?

Comment: If you can get all solutions, you can simply order them lexicographically and pick the first. In your last example that would be $E,G,H,F$.

Comment: Good point. Then the question remains how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are programming the sort algorithm, unless you use a random choice of the child of a parent node, your algorithm will always return the same answer. In your example, make a program that, starting from ***E***, will prefer ***G*** to ***H*** and so forth. It will always answer ***E, G, H, F***.
EDIT : here is the algo.

```
While there is a vertex in the graph do
    Display the vertex with 0 incoming edge (if many choose the one with lower lexical order)
    Remove it and its out-going links from the graph
end
```

The order is what the algo displays.
It will start with ***E***. It is displayed and removed. Then ***G*** and ***H*** are candidates. The one with the **lower lexical order** is ***G***. It is displayed and removed. The next candidate is ***H***. It is displayed and removed. Then ***F*** is displayed and removed.
The algo make a breadth-first search. Its display is ***E, G, H, F***.

Comment: That will not work. If my program "prefers ***G*** to ***H***", because of the alphabetic sorting, then it will also prefer ***F*** to ***G*** and also always answer ***E, H, F, G***.

Comment: But _**F**_ is not a child of _**E**_. It will never be compared to _**G**_. OK, I edit my answer.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks a lot!